# After upgrading specs2 to 2.10 matcher 'haveTheSameElementsAs' seems lost

Tags: scala, specs2

Recently I have upgraded my specs2 to 2.10-2.3.11 and apparently after that compiler can't recognize matcher `must haveTheSameElementsAs`. I couldn't find where they moved it or similar matcher in specs2. Any idea where is it/ what I should use instead of that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `collection must contain(exactly(collection2:_*))`.